# button with 2 link targets - depending on cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, imagebutton

I would like to create a button (image). It should be checked whether a cookie is present or not. If yes, then go "onclick" to "Link A" - if not, then go to "Link B".

```
if (document.cookie)
{
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('xxxxxxxx=true') > -1)
    {
        window.location.replace("http://link-a");
    }else{
        window.location.href = "http://link-b";
    }
}
```

---

HTML Button:

```
<a href="#">
<img class="button1" src="image.png" alt="" style="width: 30; margin:0px auto; display:block;">
</a>
```

Please help...  :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I don't think window.location is the right way to handle the problem. Instead, you should check the cookie and update the link's href attribute.

This should work:

**HTML**

```
<!-- I gave the link tag an id -->
<a id="link" href="#">
  <img ... />
</a>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
  var hasCookie = document.cookie ? true : false,  
      link = document.getElementById('link');

    if (hasCookie) { 
      if (document.cookie.indexOf('xxxxxxxx=true') > -1) {
        link.setAttribute("href", "http://link-a");           
      }
    }
    else{
      link.setAttribute("href", "http://link-b");
    }
  }
})();
```

**Edit:** I just noticed that this was tagged as jQuery. The jQuery version of the above solution would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  if (document.cookie)
  {
    var hasCookie = document.cookie ? true : false,
        link = $('a#link');

    if (hasCookie) { 
      if (document.cookie.indexOf('xxxxxxxx=true') > -1) {
        link.attr("href", "http://link-a");           
      }
    }
    else{
      link.attr("href", "http://link-b");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your answer! It seems that i still have an issue - e.g. with the href="#". The button just loads the current page.

Comment: Ah, I see now. So you _never_ want the link's href to equal '#'. In that case see my latest edited answer. You can also accomplish the goal by making the default html href equal to `http://link-b` + getting rid of the else block.